# IDE for websphere/jython

Tags: ide, websphere, jython, rad, websphere-7

I would like to develop administrative jython-scripts for WebSphere 7. Is there any IDE (or may be plugins for eclipse) which provides code auto-completition functions, ability to start/stop server, debug jython scripts? I know that there is the Application Server Toolkit 6.1 but it is for WebSphere 6.1 and couldn't be applied to WebSphere 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WAS 7, "IBM Rational Application Developer Assembly and Deploy V7.5" has replaced the AST.  "IBM Rational Application Developer V7.5 for WebSphere" is a superset of "IBM Rational Application Developer Assembly and Deploy V7.5".  Both ship with your copy of WAS, but the license for RAD is just a trial one, while the license for the assembly and deploy tool does not expire. See:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/catk_assemblytools.html

Either should allow you to create/debug Jython/wsadmin scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As for Python/Jython there is [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I got frustrated with Jython Wsadmin myself. I built a tool that uses a Groovy-DSL for my configuration:

- Datasource
- JdbcProvider
- SIB, JmsQueue, Top
- ActivationSpec
- etc.

You can add it as a project dependency in IntelliJ and you got completion and inspection. You will be able to step through the script with a Debugger as in a regular Java program. I didn't test the start/stop server functionality, though.

I went as far as to make it useful for my purpose, pull requests welcome:
https://github.com/revaultch/wsadmin-groovy